# Recibiendo signo de interrogación en clase java desde jsp

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, utf-8, caracteres

Tengo un `.jsp` que tiene un `textarea`. Cuando recupero el valor del `textarea` (en una función javascript), este contiene el valor `importación`, pero cuando lo envío a la clase `java` y lo recupero, la variable java contiene `importaci?on`

Intenté hacer esto pero no funciona:

jsp:

```
var varValue = varExt.value.replace(/ó/g, "%F23");
```

y en la clase java:

```
name = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(name, "UTF-8");
```

alguna idea?

**Finalmente lo he resuelto añadiendo URIEncoding="ISO-8859-15" en el  connector de tomcat.**

Comment: Necesitaríamos más información: ¿No usas ningún framework? Qué encoding tienes definido en los JSP?

Comment: Finalmente lo he resuelto añadiendo URIEncoding="ISO-8859-15" en el  connector de tomcat.

Comment: Yo resolví poniendo UTF-8 en el contector *Y* en todos los JSP, pero hay varias opciones

Comment: a parte del URIEncoding, hay que añadir alguna cosa mas en algún otro fichero? porque en algunas clases me decodifica bien pero en otras no :(

Comment: Asegúrate de que todo JSP tiene en la primera línea `<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>`

Comment: Lo tiene puesto y la variable en la clase java me recoge un %23 en lugar de &

Answer (score 0):

Intenta cambiando en la función de javascript por el unicode de esta manera `"importaci\u00F3n"` así estarías llamando a un carácter especial que te permite poner colocar la `ó` con tilde.

En todo caso acá están más caracteres especiales con sus unicodes para javascript:
https://lefunes.wordpress.com/2007/11/14/caracteres-especiales-en-javascript/